# Bridge Protocol to collect transaction fees in hyperledger-fabric

Tags: plugins, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I want to create a blockchain platform base on hyperledger-fabric where organizations who want to use this platform will have to pay me whenever they query or invoke transaction. My idea is to write a chaincode "mainchain" to save information. accounts of organizations using our platform (id, balance ..) whenever query or invoke, transactions will go through the plugin (endorsement).

I can use `GetStateMultipleKeys()` function to get balance information, check If the balance of that organization has enough balance, it will continue to endorse that transaction and deduct the fee from the balance, if there is not enough balance, it will not endorse the transaction.

However, I have a problem but I have not found a solution to solve. It is balance and the balance after endorse is finished for that transaction need to subtract that balance, but according to my information, the plugin cannot call to enter chaincode to subtract balance (balance) in "mainchain"? Think about using call API except for balance from the plugin. Also, the endorse plugin has a way to subtract balance in the "mainchain",

Sorry for my expression may be difficult to understand.

Hope your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add to mainchain a special function that moves funds from the user's account to the peer's account and it will be used to pay for queries and invokes.

Let's say that you move 1 unit of funds from the user's account to the peer's account, for every 1000 queries or invokes.

So, the endorsement plugin would check [by accessing the state](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/core/handlers/endorsement/api/state/state.go#L15-L27) that you pre-paid for enough endorsements before it would authorize the operation.

I think that if you invest enough effort, you might be able to use the [SigningIdentity capabilities](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/core/handlers/endorsement/api/identities/identities.go#L14-L29) of the endorsement plugin, to actually send a transaction to the orderer from the plugin itself (I know it sounds a bit complex).

So you can have the endorsement plugin, count the number of endorsements/queries done to it, and periodically write it to the blockchain.

It gets tricky because you can have multiple peers, but - I believe you can make it work somehow.

Comment: "I think that if you invest enough effort, you might be able to use the SigningIdentity capabilities of the endorsement plugin, to actually send a transaction to the orderer from the plugin itself (I know it sounds a bit complex)."

Very good idea please explain this idea more clearly. Thank you!!

Comment: The endorsement plugin, gives you the ability to sign a payload.
This means that you can use it to actually send a transaction like a client.
come to https://chat.hyperledger.org and ask me if you still don't understand...

Answer (score 0):

What is the plugin that you are refering to?

I think according to your problem you want to have a balance for an organization, if the balance runs out transaction should not happen, in that case a simple approach will be to keep the balance as a state (maybe a private state), and everytime a transaction happens you can change the state of that org by -1. **GetStateMultipleKeys** loops through GetState for each of the keys, so it should be used judiciously for performance reasons.

Comment: "you can change the state of that org by -1" this is my problem. I dont have way to do it. Because in plugin endorse cant change it.